# Операции с процентами в переменных

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная `p = 2` мне нужно отнять от нее 50%, как это можно реализовать, и можно ли это сделать со строкой? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const persent = '25%';
let value = 2;
value = value - (value / 100 * parseFloat(persent));
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)

Comment: А если бы в условии надо было отнять не 50%, а, скажем, 25%?

Comment: @Yaant, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

```js
Number.prototype.percent = function(percent = 100) {
 const result = this.valueOf() / 100 * Math.abs(parseFloat(percent));
 return Math.sign(parseFloat(percent)) === -1 ? this.valueOf() - result : result;
};

const num = 200;
const halfNum = num.percent('50%');
const quarterNum = num.percent(25);
const x2Num = num.percent(200);
const takeQuarterNum = num.percent(-25);
//const takeQuarterNum = num.percent('-25%');


console.log({
  'Число': num,
  'Половина от числа': halfNum,
  'Четверть от числа': quarterNum,
  'В 2 раза больше': x2Num,
  'Отнять четверть от числа': takeQuarterNum
});
```

Решил более развёрнуто оставить функцию для вычисления процента от числа. Взял готовое вычисление у Дмытрыка, и решил добавить в прототип новую функцию, которая будет возвращать % от числа.

Свойство `Number.prototype` представляет прототип конструктора.

В прототип поместил функцию возвращающую процент от числа:

```
function(percent = 100) {
    return this.valueOf() / 100 * parseFloat(percent);
};
```

`this.valueOf()` - возвращает задействованное число.

Ну а дальше можно использовать функцию в любом числе.

```
(число).функция(параметр)
```

`(200).percent(50)` - от числа 200, взять 50%.

---

**UPD:**

Обновил ответ в соответствии с вопросом.

Теперь если вы хотите отнять % от числа, то поставьте перед параметром минус и сможете получить число, от которого отняли какой-то процент.

(Увидел у **Дмытрык**а правку и решил обновить свой ответ).

Comment: Очень подробно, большое спасибо ! ;)

Comment: @Tryr обновил ответ под ваши требования